# Is there anything like online Ubuntu O/S

Tags: ssh, cloud

I use 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 but sometimes i need 32 bit Ubuntu for some specific purpose. So i keep 32 bit Ubuntu installed in virtual box. I wonder if there is any service like online Ubuntu where we could make an account, connect using ssh etc and use it just like our own PC.

Comment: Have you considered renting a VPS server? Some providers offer Ubuntu as an option. Do note that it will be less responsive, won't have graphical interface and will cost more than just using your current solution.

Comment: @devius: It can absolutely have a graphical interface, accessible via VNC/RDP or even X forwarding; it doesn't have to be noticeably less responsive provided it is geographically close and has decent resources.

Comment: Most VPSes don't offer that, and some physically can't handle that, @izx

Answer (score 2):

Use Amazon ec2 ubuntu image. You pay per hour of usage time
Check http://cloud.ubuntu.com